# Add new rules in Foundation interchange after the page has been loaded

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I am building a WordPress theme with users profiles.

In the users profile page, I like to allow the end user to upload his/her personal picture. At the time of page rendering I am using the Foundation interchange, in order to display the correct image size based on the screen size.

Until now everything looks good, but after the user Choose the desired picture for his profile how can I repeat the same process by using the Foundation Interchange ?

More specific:

My code that replacing the current picture looks like this:

```
var $img_elm = $('#profile_picture');

attachment          =   $media_dialog.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

$attachment_id      =   attachment.id;
$attachment_medium  =   attachment.sizes.thumbnail.url;
$attachment_large   =   attachment.sizes.custom_size.url;

$interchange_url    =   '[' + $attachment_large + ', (default)], [' + $attachment_medium + ', (small)], [' + $attachment_medium + ', (medium)], [' + $attachment_large + ', (large)]';

$img_elm.attr('data-interchange', $interchange_url);
```

So, based on **[Foundation documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html#adding-new-interchange-content-after-page-load)**, I should run this code at the end of the script in order to update my img element:

```
$(document).foundation();
```

But, I have already try this, and the picture still the same.

Am I doing something wrong ? Is there any other way to achive that same result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research in `Foundation.interchange.js` I found that I can use the following code in order to update the new selected image:

```
Foundation.libs.interchange.init($, 'update_images',    null);
Foundation.libs.interchange.init($, 'resize',           null);
```